# getting the lowest count value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I just want the most least repeated count like in the image 1 only to be displayed. But i am having problem

```
SELECT bidprice, user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM auction_details WHERE product_id = '1'
GROUP BY bidprice
```

Comment: Please share the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need  only the lower count result you could using limit 1

```
  SELECT bidprice, user_id, COUNT(*) my_count
  FROM auction_details WHERE product_id = '1'
  GROUP BY bidprice
  order by  my_count ASC  limit 1
```